# Where does the 'Name' property in a DBML come from?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm using Linq-To-Sql and inside my DBML there are objects built from the database connection provided.

If you click on an association line between two tables and view the properties on it, you will get the following:

- Cardinality
- Child Property

  - Access
  - Inheritance Modifier
  - **Name**
- Parent Property

  - Access
  - Inheritance Modifier
  - **Name**
- Participating Properties
- Unique

My question is, where does Linq-To-Sql get the "Name" properties from? Where is the correlation to the actual database?

I ask this because if this table happens to be a parent to several children, Linq-To-Sql will just simply name these properties, "*SomeParentName*", "*SomeParentName2*", "*SomeParentName3*" , etc. So you'd have to go into the DBML and manually change these names to something meaningful every time you update this table.

Any help you can provide would be appreciated.

Part 2 of my question might be how do you guys handle these situations?

Comment: The LINQ2SQL clases designer automatically assigns these properties based on the relationship. If the relationship is One to Many the designer will Name the child Property Name as plural. If you think the Name provided is not meaningful you can change it.

Comment: I realize that what Im asking is, where does it get the name from.

Comment: It gets it from the Table name, View name, Storeproc name or Function name in the Database

Answer (score 2):

As for the Name: It takes the child / parent and comes up with something based on some internal voodoo. Don't ask me how.

As for Part 2: If you tend to have to redo stuff every time you update something I STRONGLY suggest switching to Entity Framework. It's very similar, but you can just hit "update" and your modifications are kept.